# Is there api for get infor about network usage of an app?

Tags: ios

i want to create an app that show all app installed on the device and info about network usage of that app. Is there api for get infor about network usage?

Comment: No there's noting like this.

Comment: I saw some app on app store can do. help me any solutions?

Comment: I'll post code below how you could do it for your own app in a minute.

Answer (score 2):

Your own app can find out how much data the device as a how as used by using the code below, but there's no way of knowing how much each particular app has used. Apps like My Data Manager used to give you a breakdown per app but a) that wasn't totally accurate and b) it now longer does this now with iOS 7. There's another app that sends the data through VPN to its server and in the screenshots on the app store makes it look like it can give a breakdown per app, but that's spin but in reality it just can't except for a few and with some interaction from the user. Basically there is no guaranteed accurate way of doing it per every app.

Also there is no guaranteed accurate way of knowing all installed apps. There are some mechanisms to do a good guess of what is installed based against a database but no way of knowing definitely what is installed

```
#include <arpa/inet.h> 
#include <net/if.h> 
#include <ifaddrs.h> 
#include <net/if_dl.h>


- (void) getDataUsage
{
    NSTimeInterval elapsedTime = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate: self.timeThatDataMonitoringStarted];
    NSLog(@"********* GETTING DATA USAGE. Elapsed time: %f **************",elapsedTime);
    NSArray *data = [self getDataCounters];

    NSNumber *wifiSentSinceBoot = (NSNumber*)data[0];
    NSNumber *wifiReceivedSinceBoot = (NSNumber*)data[1];
    NSNumber *wwanSentSinceBoot = (NSNumber*)data[2];
    NSNumber *wwanReceivedSinceBoot = (NSNumber*)data[3];

    int wifiSentSinceBootAsInt      = [wifiSentSinceBoot intValue];
    int wifiReceivedSinceBootAsInt  = [wifiReceivedSinceBoot intValue];
    int wWanSentSinceBootAsInt      = [wwanSentSinceBoot intValue];
    int wWanReceivedSinceBootAsInt  = [wwanReceivedSinceBoot intValue];

    static int initialWifiSent;
    static int initialWifiReceived;
    static int initialWWanSent;
    static int initialWWanReceived;
    if (!self.initialDataValuesSet)
    {
        self.initialDataValuesSet    = YES;
        initialWifiSent     = wifiSentSinceBootAsInt;
        initialWifiReceived = wifiReceivedSinceBootAsInt;
        initialWWanSent     = wWanSentSinceBootAsInt;
        initialWWanReceived = wWanReceivedSinceBootAsInt;
    }

    int wifiSentSinceLastRetrieval     = wifiSentSinceBootAsInt - initialWifiSent;
    int wifiReceivedSinceLastRetrieval = wifiReceivedSinceBootAsInt - initialWifiReceived;
    int wWanSentSinceLastRetrieval     = wWanSentSinceBootAsInt - initialWWanSent;
    int wWanReceivedSinceLastRetrieval  = wWanReceivedSinceBootAsInt - initialWWanReceived;

    uint dataUsed = wifiSentSinceLastRetrieval + wifiReceivedSinceLastRetrieval + wWanSentSinceLastRetrieval + wWanReceivedSinceLastRetrieval;
    NSLog(@"Total data: %d", dataUsed);
}


- (NSArray *) getDataCounters
{
    BOOL   success;
    struct ifaddrs *addrs;
    const struct ifaddrs *cursor;
    const struct if_data *networkStatisc;

    int WiFiSent = 0;
    int WiFiReceived = 0;
    int WWANSent = 0;
    int WWANReceived = 0;

    NSString *name=[[NSString alloc]init];

    success = getifaddrs(&addrs) == 0;
    if (success)
    {
        cursor = addrs;
        while (cursor != NULL)
        {
            name=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%s",cursor->ifa_name];
            //   NSLog(@"ifa_name %s == %@\n", cursor->ifa_name,name);
            // names of interfaces: en0 is WiFi ,pdp_ip0 is WWAN

            if (cursor->ifa_addr->sa_family == AF_LINK)
            {
                if ([name hasPrefix:@"en"])
                {
                    networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;
                    WiFiSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                    WiFiReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                    //  NSLog(@"WiFiSent %d ==%d",WiFiSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                    //  NSLog(@"WiFiReceived %d ==%d",WiFiReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
                }

                if ([name hasPrefix:@"pdp_ip"])
                {
                    networkStatisc = (const struct if_data *) cursor->ifa_data;
                    WWANSent+=networkStatisc->ifi_obytes;
                    WWANReceived+=networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes;
                    //  NSLog(@"WWANSent %d ==%d",WWANSent,networkStatisc->ifi_obytes);
                    //  NSLog(@"WWANReceived %d ==%d",WWANReceived,networkStatisc->ifi_ibytes);
                }
            }

            cursor = cursor->ifa_next;
        }

        freeifaddrs(addrs);
    }

    return [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:WiFiSent], [NSNumber numberWithInt:WiFiReceived],[NSNumber numberWithInt:WWANSent],[NSNumber numberWithInt:WWANReceived], nil];
}
```